# php regex finding a string between two strings

Tags: php, regex, variables

I wanted to perform a regex in php. From the $str variable I want to select out common_name = Bangladesh . I wore my regex. The regex is not finding any match here. How can I fix this?

```
$str = "| conventional_long_name = People's Republic of Bangladesh | common_name = Bangladesh | image_flag = Flag of Bangladesh.svg";
    $pat = "/(?=\common_name\s=).*?(?=\s\|)/";

    if(preg_match($pat, $str, $matches)){
        echo "Matches found";
        echo $matches[0];
    } else {
        echo "No match found";
    }
```

the result shows

```
No match found
```

Comment: You need to learn how to READ and debug error messages. Everything you needed to solve the problem was in the message.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed semicolon `;` at the first line

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `;` at the end of `$str = "...."`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of your first line:

Change it to:

```
$str = "| conventional_long_name = People's Republic of Bangladesh | common_name = Bangladesh | image_flag = Flag of Bangladesh.svg";
```

Also, get a decent IDE and save yourself the trouble of asking this question on SO every time! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the semicolon on the 1st line of your code

```
  $str = "| conventional_long_name = People's Republic of Bangladesh | common_name = Bangladesh | image_flag = Flag of Bangladesh.svg";
        $pat = "/(?=\common_name\s=).*?(?=\s\|)/";

        if(preg_match($pat, $str, $matches)){
            echo "Matches found";
            echo $matches[0];
        } else {
            echo "No match found";
        }
```